# How do you add more than one css class to an <img> using image_tag?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

How do you add more than one css class to an `<img>` using image_tag?

Using `image_tag("image.png", :class => "class1, class2")` seems not to work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't separate the classes using a comma, separate them using a space...

```
image_tag("image.png", :class => "class1 class2")
```

> Note: You cannot use a space inside a class name...separate them using
>   `_` or `-`, if you use space than class 1 class 2 will be like 4 classes in which all are invalid.

Comment: and also it will work even without the parentheses like this `image_tag "image.png", :class => "class1 class2"`

Comment: @PavelNikolov Ya not aware of ruby but applied CSS base rule and answered :)

Answer (score 0):

```
The following will work:
<%= image_tag("/image.png", :class => "class1 class2")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not the correct way, because that doesn't worked for me.

Instead, I tried

```html
<%= image_tag("image.png"), :class => "media-object img-circle" %>
```

And this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I thought it might be useful to point out that, at least in Rails >= 4.2, you may pass an array of values.

```
image_tag("avatar", class: [:class1, :class_2, "img-responsive", 'img-circle'])
```

Which will produce something similar to the following:

```
<img class="class1 class_2 img-responsive img-circle" src="/assets/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" />
```

Take note if your class contains a hyphen it will need to be enclosed in quotes, else Ruby will treat anything after as a method/variable.

```
:img-responsive

undefined local variable or method `responsive' for #<#<Class:0x007fb6baa52198>:0x007fb6b982e2f0>
```

Answer (score -1):

To apply more then one class to any control or html element, you need to separate classes name with space instead comma.

for example

```
<div class="class1 class2">
// Content here.
</div>
```